# Is this design for dependency injection easy to understand?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, factory

I'm working on a project with a large existing codebase and I've been tasked with performing some re-engineering of a small portion of it.  The existing codebase does not have a lot of unit testing, but I would like at least the portion I'm working on to have a full suite of unit tests with good code coverage.

Because the existing codebase was not designing with unit testing in mind, I need to make some structural changes in order to support isolation of dependencies.  I'm trying to keep the impact on existing code as small as possible, but I do have a bit of leeway to make changes to other modules.  I'd like feedback on whether the changes I've made make sense or if there is a better way to approach the problem.  I made the following changes:

1. I extracted interfaces for all of the non-trivial classes on which my 'coordinator' class depends.  The other developers grudgingly allowed this, with some minor grumbling.
2. I modified the coordinator class to refer only to the interfaces for its operation.
3. I could not use a DI framework, but I had to inject a large number of dependencies (including additional dependency instantiation as part of the class operation), so I modified the coordinator class to look like this (domain-specific names simplified):

.

```
public sealed class Coordinator
{
    private IFactory _factory;

    public Coordinator(int param)
        : this(param, new StandardFactory())
    {            
    }

    public Coordinator(int param, IFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        //Factory used here and elsewhere...
    }

    public interface IFactory
    {
        IClassA BuildClassA();

        IClassB BuildClassB(string param);

        IClassC BuildClassC();
    }

    private sealed class StandardFactory : IFactory
    {
        public IClassA BuildClassA()
        {
            return new ClassA();   
        }

        public IClassB BuildClassB(string param)
        {
            return new ClassB(param);
        }

        public IClassC BuildClassC()
        {
            return new ClassC();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows for injection of a stubbed factory to return the mocked dependencies for unit testing.  My concern is that this also means any user of this class could supply their own factory to change the way the class operates, which is not really the intention.  This constructor is purely intended for unit testing, but it has the side effect of implying that additional extensibility was intended.  I don't usually see this pattern in other classes I use, which makes me wonder if I'm over-complicating and if there's a better way to achieve the required isolation.

---

NOTE: There's something weird going on with the code formatting, so I apologize for the poor formatting above.  Not sure why it won't let me format it correctly.

Comment: So is the Coodinator responsible for creating multiple instances of ClassA, ClassB and ClassC?  Or does it need just once instance of each?  I guess I'm trying to determine if ClassA/B/C are dependencies of the Coordinator or results/output of the Coordinator.

Comment: @Patrick, Some of these will only be instantiated once (in the constructor), but others will be instantiated multiple times.  All of these are dependencies of the Coordinator, but they're privately owned and managed by the Coordinator.  They are used to implement the Coordinator, but are never exposed publicly.  Their implementation and behavior is complex enough that I want to stub them out for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed design is a variant of **Constructor Injeciton** sometimes known as **Bastard Injection**. In a greenfield situation I would consider Bastard Injection an anti-pattern, but it's a good compromise in a brownfield situation like the one you describe.

You shouldn't really be concerned about the implied extensibility of the Coordinator class. Done correctly, [testability *is* extensibility](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/06/05/TestabilityIsReallyTheOpenClosedPrinciple.aspx), so ideally the injected IFactory should represent a proper Domain Concept that enables variability. I understand that this can be difficult/impossible to achieve at a single stroke when you're refactoring from legacy code, but that's the direction in which your code base should be moving.

In any case, if your coworkers already begrudge the *extraction* of interfaces, they are probably not very likely to interpret the IFactory constructor parameter as an extensibility point.

Good luck.

Comment: I hadn't heard the terms Bastard Injection or brownfield situation before, but they're quite descriptive.  There's already a perception in some circles here that simply extracting interfaces adds unnecessary complexity, so I want to make sure the injection design can enable testing without raising red flags.

Comment: In case you are not aware of it, there's an excellent book by Michael Feathers called *Working Effectively with Legacy Code* that should apply very well to your situation. However, from your description, I'm not sure your colleagues are going to like its recommendations...

Comment: thanks for the book recommendation.  I've been reading through it and enjoying it quite a bit.  It brings up the point that putting legacy code under test can make it uglier at first and certainly some of the dependency-breaking techniques he provides can be pretty ugly.  I think the compromise will be worth it in the long run and I'm slowly being given responsibility for more of the project, so hopefully I can give Frankenstein some better stitches as his boundaries become better defined.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider making the constructor that accepts an `IFactory` internal -- that would prevent other users outside the assembly from "extending" your Coodinator.  Then use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to expose it only to your unit tests.

Comment: This is a good compromise.  If you encountered this code while taking it over to maintain it, would it be  clear to you what the intention was?  My main concern (and the concern of my colleagues) is that this adds unnecessary complexity, though I personally believe the benefits of having a testable class outweigh the extra complexity.

Comment: I think its a stretch to say it adds complexity -- I think that is just more FUD.  As @Mark Seemann said, it's a good compromise for the situation you're in.  Over time, you will hopefully be able to "refactor it out" as the application grows (since you'll have all those unit tests to ensure you don't break existing functionality!)